# Spring nested @Transactional method stores record to db before parent @Transactional method executes

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactional

I have Spring 4 with Hibernate 4. My problem is that I want to have transaction on imported data. I parse JSON and next store it to DB. But when something will go wrong (server will go down). I don't want to have part of data in DB.

I have method:

```
@Transactional
private void processJson()
```

in which I call in loop:

```
recipientGroupSellInService.saveOrUpdate(perDay);
```

it looks much like this:

```
@Transactional
private void processJson(){
    for(int i : iSet){
        recipientGroupSellInService.saveOrUpdate(perDay[i]);
    }
}
```

save or update:

```
@Transactional
public Boolean saveOrUpdate(T model) {
    getSession().saveOrUpdate(model);
    return true;
}
```

so after calling `saveOrUpdate` data is stored to DB, and not roll back on general failure of method `processJson`.

What should I look after or change to have "real transaction" on method `processJson`?

Comment: what is getSession() returning?

Comment: getSession: `protected Session getSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }`

Comment: Make sure you aren't duplicating your components (component scanning in both the `ContextLoaderListener` and `DispatcherServlet` might lead to duplicate components one not transasctional due to absence of `<tx:annotation-driven />` in that context.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I don't have duplicates, its all annotation-driven with `<context:annotation-config/>
    <bean class="pl.com.eurohost.vmi.AppConfig"/>`

Answer (score 0):

The transaction is started in `processJson()`. Since your `saveOrUpdate()` is using the regular `@Transactional`, it will join the previously started transaction.

If there is a problem (i.e. a `RuntimeException`), anything made by or from `processJson()` will be rolled back.

Are you claiming that you're seeing behaviour where partial data is written?

Comment: yes, I start doing import, it takes about minute, after start I can see data in DB (SQL SERVER) and after I kill process, all data remains in DB

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured the PlatformTransactionManager? (either from xml or from Configuration)

Eg:

```
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: I have `@Autowired
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }` in `@EnableTransactionManagement
public class AppConfig implements SchedulingConfigurer {`

Comment: after starting app I get log like this:
12:14:08,263  INFO TransactionFactoryInitiator:62 - HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)